# Two Consecutive Alert Views and then Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm trying to figure out how to use two alert views consecutively, and THEN segue to the next controller.

The *requestStartTime* and *requestEndTime* are UIAlertViews.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[self requestStartTime];

}




- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 1)

{

    [self requestEndTime];

}{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"report" sender:nil];
}
}
```

I need to **segue** after the **second** alert view has been clicked. My problem is that it segues and opens the requestEndTime in the second view controller. I need to add another

```
if (buttonIndex ==1)
```

statement somewhere? Would appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store your `UIAlerView` somewhere and in [alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:] do simple if like this:

```
if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView == self.firstAlertView)
{
    [self requestEndTime];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView == self.secondAlertView)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"report" sender:nil];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store references to the alert views. It is one option. An easier option is to set the alert view's tag. Use a different tag for each alert and check the tag in the alert view delegate method.